# SQL to merge max values from multiple rows

Tags: sql, max, rows

suppose I have a table

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|   id   |   value1   |   value2   |   value3   |
 -----------------------------------------------
|   102  |     10     |      1     |     3      |
 -----------------------------------------------
|   102  |     2      |      11    |     0      |
 -----------------------------------------------
|   102  |     0      |      9     |     13     |
 -----------------------------------------------
|   102  |     3      |      5     |     7      |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

and for each distinct id I want to return a row with max value in columns value1, value2 and value3, i.e.

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|   id   |   value1   |   value2   |   value3   |
 -----------------------------------------------
|   102  |     10     |     11     |     13     |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

(of course there are other ids than 102 in the table)

I managed to do it with "partition by" but the problem is that I have to use it in powerbuilder's datawindow, and as soon as I paste it there the whole IDE crashes and project gets corrupted.

I managed to create an sql that for each row does 3 inner joins with selects that return max of every column.

Is there any other easier way?

Thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT  id,
        MAX(value1) val1,
        MAX(value2) val2,
        MAX(value3) val3
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1119f/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MAX(value1) value1, MAX(value2) value2, MAX(value3) value3
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```